# Quicker way to browse through questions?

Tags: feature-request

Aside from the main page, is there a "*minimalist*" feature or button I can press whereby I can browse through the pages of,

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions

such that *only the titles appear*, without the clutter of a) the first two lines of the post, and b) tags?

The features (a) and (b) have their uses, but they can be quite distracting, and it would be nice to have the option to turn it off.

P.S: Something like the old *sci.math* where you can look at about 40 titles without scrolling down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide anything you don't want to see on SE pages with CSS rules. Try this [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) to begin with:

```
javascript:(function(){$('.excerpt,.tags,.started,.statscontainer,#sidebar,#header').css('display','none');$('#mainbar,#questions,.summary,.question-summary').css('width','100%');$('.question-summary').css({'padding':'2px','border':'none'});$('.summary a').css({'color':'#000','font-family':'monospace','font-size':'16px'});})()
```

[image: minimal]

I changed the font to monospace trying to recreate the charm of sci.math :)

The bookmarklet only affects the current page (i.e.,  you first navigate to  `Questions`, then click the bookmark). It is not a sticky setting.  If this (after some tuning) is the sort of look you want to see, you can enforce the settings permanently by adding a user stylesheet to your browser (e.g., using Stylish for Firefox or Stylebot for Chrome):

```
.excerpt, .tags, .started, .statscontainer, #sidebar, #header {
    display: none;
}
#mainbar, #questions, .summary, .question-summary {
    width:  100%;
}
.question-summary { 
    padding: 2px; 
    border: none; 
}
.summary a { 
   color: #000;
   font-family: monospace;
   font-size: 16px; 
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: @Post No Bulls: Thanks! I went to the Wikipedia link and it said "...installation of a bookmarklet is performed by creating a new bookmark, and pasting the code into the URL destination field". I use Chrome and after I created the bookmark, I tried to edit it by replacing the url field with the code. It didn't work, so what did I do wrong?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Could be a copy-and-paste mistake. You can drag the same  link from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/js9Tv/1/).

Comment: It didn't work. Bear with me, but I noticed that in the example in Wikipedia, it still showed the URL of the destination imbedded in the code. In your code, how does it "know" to go to mathstackexchange.com?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII It does not do that. Bookmarklet only hides things from a page that is already shown in the browser. So, it works when you have `math.stackexchange.com/questions` page open. As I wrote in the post, the bookmarklet is not a permanent solution. It is meant for testing the layout. A permanent change would be with a user stylesheet.

Comment: Oh, I got it! I had to have /questions page open. It worked. (I knew there was a missing assumption somewhere.)  :)

Comment: I changed the font to 'times roman', then 'arial'. It's quite fun, this _power_ to change the layout of a webpage.  :)